# Protocol Buffers and Hadoop

Tags: serialization, hadoop, protocol-buffers, avro

I am new to the Hadoop world. I know that Hadoop has its own serialization mechanism called Writables. And that AVRO is another such library. I wanted to know whether we can write map-reduce jobs using the Google's protocol buffer serialization? If yes then can someome point to a good example to get me started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twitter has published their [elephant-bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird) library which allows hadoop to work with protocol buffers files.